# Why Is the Web Crawler I made with Python not working?

Tags: python, css

I am following a tutorial on webscraping by Justin Duke of Digital Ocean.  Here is the link to the tutorial

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-crawl-a-web-page-with-scrapy-and-python-3

When I run my code, the web crawler displays the following error:

'BrickSetSpider.parse callback is 'not defined'.

I'm not sure what this means.

Here is the code I used.

```
import scrapy


class BrickSetSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "brickset_spider"
    start_urls = ['http://brickset.com/sets/year-2016']

def parse(self, response):
        SET_SELECTOR = '.set'
        for brickset in response.css(SET_SELECTOR):

            NAME_SELECTOR = 'h1 ::text'
            yield {
                'name': brickset.css(NAME_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
            }
```

I am also pretty new to Python. So, I would appreciate it if your answer to my question was written in such a way that a noobie would be able to understand it.

Comment: If that's your actual indentation then perhaps you should add four spaces before `def parse(...)` so that it becomes a method of the class.

Comment: Definitely an indentation issue, add parse function inside main class with proper indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
import scrapy


class BrickSetSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "brickset_spider"
    start_urls = ['http://brickset.com/sets/year-2016']

    def parse(self, response):
        SET_SELECTOR = '.set'

        for brickset in response.css(SET_SELECTOR):
            NAME_SELECTOR = 'h1 ::text'
            yield {
            'name': brickset.css(NAME_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
                  }
```